# Ajax, datepicker value with serialized form post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When I post a serialized form data to a parse php file my date field is not sent through. I make use of jquery's datepicker.  When I do a normal post like this:

```
            //Check for valid date format
        if (!dateFormat.test(birthDate)){
            self.config.birthdayError.addClass('erroroutput').text('Please enter a valid date: YYYY-DD-MM.');
            birthdayErr = true;
            return;
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                data: 'birthday=' + birthDate,
                success: function(result){
                    result = $.trim(result);

                    if (result == 'Too young.') ....
```

This code however is not sending the birthday throough:

```
//Post the data to PHP for varification and to add the user to the database.
postData: function(){
    var self = registerUser;

    console.log('Button clicked');
    console.log(self.config.signupform.serialize());
    //Send data to php for validation
    $.ajax({
        data: self.config.signupform.serialize(),
        // dataType: 'json',
        success: function(results){
            results = $.trim(results);
```

This is clearly shown by the console.log(). return: first_name=dataEntered&last_name=dataEntered&username=dataEntered&password=dataEntered&retypepassword=dataEntered&email=dataEntered&forum_access=dataEntered&submitForm=Submit+Form

Any idea how I can cross this bridge please?

Comment: did you forget to put a `name` on datepicker `input`?

Comment: No I did not. Here are snippets of code to show what I have done:
`code`var registerUser = {
 init: function(config){
  this.config = config;

Comment: any input in a form that doesn't have `name` won't get submitted by default browser submital ( no ajax), `serialize()` therefore ignores.  it also. `name` is needed as `key` for key/value pair

Comment: No I did not. Here are snippets of code to show what I have done:
`code`var registerUser = {
 init: function(config){
  this.config = config;
                  $.ajaxSetup({
   url: 'parseFiles/parse_signup.php',
   type: 'POST'
  });

 },

        bindEvents: function() {
            this.config.submitButton.on('click', this.postData);
        },

`code`

Then I have an init method at the bottom:
`code`
birthdayInput: $('input#birthday'),
some other code.
`code`  Then I use `code`birthDate = self.config.birthdayInput.val();

Comment: Thank you I did not have a name attibute in my birthday input field.  Thanks mate:)